# How to make this vim file browser function work in neovim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, file-browser

This function integrates the fantastic lf file explorer into vim but it does not work in neovim. How would you make it work in neovim?

```
function! LF()
    let temp = tempname()
    exec 'silent !lf -selection-path=' . shellescape(temp)
    if !filereadable(temp)
        redraw!
        return
    endif
    let names = readfile(temp)
    if empty(names)
        redraw!
        return
    endif
    exec 'edit ' . fnameescape(names[0])
    for name in names[1:]
        exec 'argadd ' . fnameescape(name)
    endfor
    redraw!
endfunction
command! -bar LF call LF()
```

https://github.com/gokcehan/lf/blob/master/etc/lf.vim

Comment: I noticed when just typing `:!lf`, vim opens lf but neovim says `initializing termbox: open /dev/tty: device not configured`. Not sure how to fix that, vim has no help page for termbox.

Comment: The problem seems to be that neovim runs everything asyncronously, but I need it to run lf syncronously and wait for it to close. How do you do that?